# Setting up New warehouse/inventory location/address

Tags: sitecore-commerce

Our Development Environment: Sitecore XP 9.1.1 , Sitecore XC 9.1.0, Habitat Storefront

We are trying to figure out where the location/address is stored inside default storefront for stock information, is it possible to maintain different stock locations?

We went to inventory and trying to find the location for the storefront where we can edit the address of the warehouse for stock.

How to setup a new warehouse location with address in sitecore commerce 9.1 using SXA storefront(We used default storefront - habitat). We want to add multiple warehouse locations/addresses inside storefront.
Is there a possibility to update addresses for storefront in commerce business tools.

How to maintain Multi ware house for Default storefront?

Regards,
Manik

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this isn't supported OOB. You will need to extend the InventorySet Entity with a new Component (WarehouseComponent) that would contain the address (Party Model).
You will then need to add a Warehouse view to Bizfx InventorySet View, to support add/Edit/remove Warehouse.

Comment: Thanks for your information, Is there any specific document which provides the information of maintaining multi ware houses?